# Xamarin's F# interactive pad cannot find mono

Tags: xamarin, f#, mono

On OSX.

When I open the pad I get this error message: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.4/bin/fsharpi: line 24: exec: mono: not found

However I can build and run F# programs, so Xamarin obviously does find mono.

Comment: Are you able to run either "fsharpi" or "mono" from the terminal?  On my system, those two are available via symlinks from /usr/bin.  I presume /usr/bin is in your path; perhaps for some reason, the symlinks did not get created.

Comment: Yes, I can run both these commands from the terminal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue and managed to solve it as follows: fsharpi is a shell script; it fails on line 24:

```
$EXEC mono $DEBUG $MONO_OPTIONS /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.4/lib/mono/4.5/fsi.exe --exename:$(basename "$0") "$@"
```

Apparently, when Xamarin launch fsharpi it does not find the mono executable, even if apparently the $PATH variable is correctly set and fsharpi can be launched from the terminal.
On my mac the mono executable is located at "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/mono", so my fix has been to replace the line with the following:

```
MONO="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/mono"
$EXEC $MONO $DEBUG $MONO_OPTIONS /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.4/lib/mono/4.5/fsi.exe --exename:$(basename "$0") "$@"
```

It is not the most elegant solution, but there already was the fsi.exe path hardcoded in the script, so I think it is acceptable.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!